# TCPDF foreach not printing array elements twice

Tags: php, arrays, tcpdf

i'm working on a project to create a *pdf* invoice from user input.
The input is put into an array: array`('input1' => 'value1', 'input2' => 'value2')`
I let my PHP parse the array and calculate necessary height / width for TCPDF to be able to print everything with borders in the right place.
Now if the user input1 and input2 are different everything works fine, but if they are exactly the same (which is a possibility) *TCPDF* only prints the second input.

Here is my code:

```
public function PrintInvoiceContent() {
// settings
$rowcount = 0;
$borderL = 'L';
$borderR = 'R';
$firstBorder = true;
$firstInfo = true;
$lastBorder = true;
$dimensions = $this->getPageDimensions();

foreach ($this->input['invoice_content'] as $key => $value) { 
// key contains text, value contains actual amount in dollar
    // measurements
    $lines = ($this->getNumLines($key, 130) * 5);
    $rowcount = $rowcount + $lines;
    $startY = $this->GetY();
    $height = ceil($startY + $rowcount + $dimensions['bm']);

    if (floor($dimensions['hk']) - $height < 1) {
        $borderL = 'LB';
        $borderR = 'RB';
        $firstBorder = true;
        $lastBorder = false;
    } else if (floor($dimensions['hk']) - $height == 1) {
        $borderL = 'LB';
        $borderR = 'RB';
        $firstBorder = true;
        $lastBorder = true;
    }
    if ($firstBorder) {
        $this->Cell(0, 5, '', 'LTR', 1);
        if ($firstInfo) {
            $this->Cell(14, ($this->getNumLines($this->input['betreft'], 153) * 5), 'About: ', 'L', 0, 'L', false);
            $this->MultiCell(156, ($this->getNumLines($this->input['betreft'], 153) * 5), $this->input['About'], 'R', 'L', false);
 // prints discription of bill contents
            $this->Cell(0, 5, '', 'LR', 1, 'L', false);
            $firstInfo = false;
        }
        $this->MultiCell(130, $lines, $key, $borderL, 'L', false, 0);
        $this->Cell(40, $lines, $value, $borderR, 1, 'L', false);
        $firstBorder = false;
    } else {
        $this->MultiCell(130, $lines, $key, $borderL, 'L', false, 0);
        $this->Cell(40, $lines, $value, $borderR, 1, 'L', false);
    }
    $this->Cell(0, 2, '', 'LR', 1);
  }
}
```

If the user input varies as much as 1 character everything works fine.
Does anyone know why the first input is omitted if the pieces of input are exactly the same?

Comment: To be clear, does the problem occur when the $value is identical or the $key? Just checking that the problem isn't that you've accidentally overwritten a value in your array by attempting to add two values with the same key.

Comment: @JamesG to be clear :$ I was overwriting my values by adding them with the same key... I figured it out like an hour after posting this. Stupid on my part to not realise that before. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Cool - glad you sorted it out. :-)